# Retrieving characters from strings in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list containing the following:

```
['$GPGLL', '5305.9132', 'N', '00019.1938', 'E', '', 'A', 'A*46\r\n']
```

I need to retrieve for example, the first 2 digits of the second item, so I get '53'. I need to do similar for quite a few chunks of data.

I know how to get the second item from a list and I know how to get specific characters from a string, but combining the two...

```
tms = "$GPGLL,5305.9132,N,00019.1938,E,,A,A*46\r\n"                                  
bits = tms.split(',')
print(bits)
temp = (bits[1])
print(temp[0:2])
```

The code has the desired effect, but the use of a temporary variable to achieve what I want in 2 steps just seems inelegant.

Is there a better way?

Comment: so do `tms.split(',')[1][0:2]` right?

Comment: I don't see doing it in 2 steps a problem though. It actually makes code easier to read instead. If there's some special meaning for the 2nd element in the list, you can give it a more meaningful name. I think the 2nd element could probably be named `latitude` here?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks ever so much for the help @Jean-FrançoisFabre. New to Python, still got a lot to learn.

Comment: Why invent your own NMEA parser instead of just using an existing one, such as https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2?

Comment: Quite right @ujhuyz0110 just wanted to break it down for formatting - got a whole load of other NMEA strings to play with too.

Comment: More of a practical task to cut my teeth on than anything else @NPE, but thanks for pointing me in that direction. Do you know of anything that can do NMEA2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both subscripts in one line if you want:

```
print(bits[1][0:2])
```

Though as @ujhuyz0110 mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587164/retrieving-characters-from-strings-in-lists#comment99752503_56587164),

> I don't see doing it in 2 steps a problem though. It actually makes code easier to read instead. If there's some special meaning for the 2nd element in the list, you can give it a more meaningful name. I think the 2nd element could probably be named `latitude` here?

Comment: even though concise the code is not safe and doesn't handle errors, exceptions. better to check lengths and other possible errors than to shorten code

Comment: @vk-code Eh? This code isn't any less safe than OP's. Tracebacks would be a bit harder to read since there's more operations on one line, but that's it.

Comment: my comment was for the person who posted the Q. you just tried to answer his Q. My point was simple, instead of shorting code add more error handling make it reliable.